# PowerShell command Start-Process not getting executed on remote

Tags: sql-server, powershell, jenkins-pipeline, remote-server, windows-server

I have the below `PowerShell` script which runs form `Jenkins` on node of `windows server 2019` (it suppose to run `deploy` on `sql server`):

```
$Username = $args[0]
$Password = $args[1]
$Env= $args[2]


$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force 
$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username,$pass

echo "********  Start SQL Deploy  ********"

echo "-----  B4 Start-Process Powershell.exe  -----"
Start-Process -FilePath "msbuild" -ArgumentList '"Database Services\Database Services.sqlproj"','/t:deploy','/p:Configuration=Release','/p:TargetConnectionString=$Env','/p:BlockOnPossibleDataLoss=True','/p:TargetDatabase="test"','-fl','-flp:logfile=msbuild.log' -wait -LoadUserProfile -credential $cred 
echo "-----  After Start-Process Powershell.exe  -----"
```

and my output is:

```
********  Start SQL Deploy  ********

    -----  B4 Start-Process Powershell.exe  -----
    -----  After Start-Process Powershell.exe  -----
```

We can clearly see `Start-Process` was not executed.
It's important to say it works locally for me, and only when I move to work with `node`, it started to happens.

I saw similar issue was raised in jenkins forum, but no one commented on that:
[JENKINS-63978](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-63978)

Comment: Try adding `-RedirectStandardError` and `-RedirectStandardOutput` to log that output to files.

Comment: It works for you locally but not on the node? It's important to ask, is msbuild installed and somewhere in the PATH?

Comment: Yes, the PATH of msbuild include in the system variables PAHT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer here (also was taken from some SO thread):

https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2317074-powershell-command-start-process-not-getting-executed-on-remote?page=1#entry-9166826